# Java / parse Object and load its fields into JTree

Tags: java, parsing, reflection, jtree

Short explanation of my problem, I need to parse an object and put its content into a JTree. I know the object can have fields of primitive types, but also other objects. How can I achieve that parsing, is reflection something I should use? I have no clue right now.

The structure would look something like that:

```
-object1
    |
    fieldname1 = 1256
    |
    fieldname2 = 5623
    |
    object2
    |  |
    |  fieldname1 = 154
    |  |
    |  fieldname2 = 190
    |
    object3
       |
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use Reflection API to discover object fields, and fill the JTree node values.

Recursively process each object as follows:

- add a node to the tree
- process objects from fields declared in your object's class (using `Class.getDeclaredFields()`)
- process objects from fields in each superclass of your object (`Class.getDeclaredFields()` doesn't return inherited fields)

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of how you would get at the data you're looking for and dumping it to the console. I have no experience with JTree, so I can't help you there.

#### Basic technique

```
for (Field field : myInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    String name = field.getName();
    value = field.get(myInstance).toString();
    System.out.println(name + ": " + value);
}
```

#### With error catching

It's a good idea to incorporate error catching into this as uninitialized fields will cause errors.

```
for (Field field : myInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    try {
        String name = field.getName();
        String value = "null";
        try {
            value = field.get(myInstance).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // this probably means the field was null
        }
        System.out.println(name + ": " + value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("problem with reflection: " + e);
    }
}
```